pulseaudio doesnt work before login - 'cannot open audio device' on MPD server
I don't want to get into it I am using a crappy knockoff thinkpad with a dodgy spacebar. My music server is on another crappy laptop running fedora 20, mpd and full of music. The damn thing needs me to login everytime before pulseaudio will play anything. So it won't be a proper server until someone on here tells me how to switch it on before login. So when it logs itself out I wont lose my music. Pleeease help.
